# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable while using math.ceil

Tags: python

I've got above error while counting variable like below.

```
EIRP_ant = [9296, 9296, 9296, 7868, 7868, 7868];
r_max = math.ceil((sum(EIRP_ant) / (4 * math.pi() * 0.1)) ** 0.5);
```

Does anyone know why this error appears?

Comment: Welcome to SO! please read [how-to-ask] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) thoroughly. Specifically, you should put code within a code block.

In your case, the solution is simply remove the parenthesis after `math.pi` as `pi` is simply a [constant](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You get**:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

**Because**:

`math.pi` is a `float` not a function

**Hence**:

```
import math

EIRP_ant = [9296, 9296, 9296, 7868, 7868, 7868]
print(math.ceil((sum(EIRP_ant) / (4 * math.pi * 0.1)) ** 0.5))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
203
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get `X is not callable` error you have to look for wrongly-placed `()`.

`math.pi` is a float, not a function. Change `math.pi()` to `math.pi`.